# How to filter out nonexistent parameter keys, before using them as attributes in an object assignment statement?

Tags: ruby, hash, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5

I am passing a hash of optional keys, with object id values, as parameters to a rails controller.  So I need to be able to filter out the keys that do not exist on my params before storing the active record to my_object.  Next, I need to store my_object record as an attribute on my_model. However, I am getting the following error when attempting to assign my_object as an attribute on my_model (see last line in code below).  Is there a problem with how I am using a symbol as the attribute name?

> **ERROR Message: can't write unknown attribute `key_1` excluded from capture: DSN not set
> app_1         |
> app_1         | ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute `key_1`):**

```
my_mode = Reports::SomeModel.new
[  :key_1,
   :key_2,
   :key_3,
   :key_4,
   :key_5,
   :key_6
].each do |key| params.has_key?(key)
    my_object = ObjectClass.find(params[key])
    my_model[key] = my_object
  end
```

Comment: I am very unclear on the question here. Did you over obfuscate the question? You are manually setting the "keys" so if `Reports::SomeModel` does not have that attribute you should remove that from the "key" list

Comment: Yes, I attempted to make the example as generic as possible.  However, key_1 is an attribute on the model.  It will work if I use dot notation, as follows.  It fails when I try to make it set the attribute on my_model dynamically with angle bracket notation.
 my_model.key_1 = ObjectClass.find params[:key_1]

Comment: Resolved by adding: my_model.send("#{key}=", my_object)

Comment: The normal way to do this is with [ActionController::Parameters#permit](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Parameters/permit), see the docs on [strong parameters](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)